# Solidity for loop over a huge amount of data

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I want to use a function to find all tokens of a user in solidity, so I use a for loop to iterate over all tokens and look if the addresses do match. The totalSupply() of tokens is around 10Mio, and this seems to be too much for the for-loop. The following function does only work for totalSupply() of less than 500000, and I don't know what actually the problem is. Above 500000 it runs the function, but the result I get back is empty, also if the user owns tokens. Does solidity have a problem with huge for loops?

```
function tokensOfOwner(address _owner) external view returns(uint256[] ownerTokens) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);

        if (tokenCount == 0) {
            // Return an empty array
            return new uint256[](0);
        } else {
            uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](tokenCount);
            uint256 total = totalSupply();
            uint256 resultIndex = 0;
            uint256 id;

            for (id = 1; id <= total; id++) {
                if (IndexToOwner[id] == _owner) {
                    result[resultIndex] = id;
                    resultIndex++;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Edit: I made a test function to see what the error could be, and somehow the maximum loop size is around 3'840'000 iterations, then somehow i always get back 0. Does anyone know if there is a bug in solidity for huge loops?

```
function testLoop(uint256 num) external view returns(uint256 res) {
        uint256 i=0;
        uint256 cnt=0;

        for(i;i<num;i++) {
            cnt++;
        }

        return cnt;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does solidity have a problem with huge for loops?

Yes, but it's not a bug. You're hitting the [gas limit](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#gas-limit-and-loops).

I can't think of any reason why you'd want to track token ownership the way you are attempting to. The total balance owned by an address stored in a `mapping(address => uint)` is not sufficient? This seems similar to tracking the serial number on a dollar bill so you can audit the history of who owned it.

If you absolutely need something like this, don't loop through your supply in the method. Simply store each id in a `mapping(address => uint256[])` and return that when this function is called. Even with this approach, tracking the state of ownership when tokens transfer frequently is going to cost you a lot in transaction fees.

EDIT - To address comment:

constant/pure functions only indicate whether or not the function can write to/read from the contract state. It still takes resources to execute these functions, and therefore consumes gas. The difference you're thinking of is that the caller may not be charged for the gas. If a constant function is called from a client with a local, fully synced non-light node, then there won't be a charge (after all, you're using your own resources). constant functions are not free when called from within a transaction.

Notice the note in Remix for the cost when running a constant function:

[image]

Comment: Hmm ok, but the function above seems not to consume gas when I bind it into a contract and run it on remix.ethereum.org in the ropsten test net. Is this because of "external view"? Will this function consume  gas when I put it on the real net? I will anyway try to use your method with mapping, thank you.